# На удалённом ответе после нажатия на кнопку показа комментариев ничего не происходит, хотя пишет, что комментарии есть

Tags: дефект, удаление-ответов

Например, в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1225051/15479).

[image: Дефектный ответ]

Comment: Это баг, комментарии удалены. Про такое уже писали, но вроде только на 1 коммент ошибка была.

Comment: Вроде бы комментарии удалены после удаления ответа. Только я не понимаю, как, потому что в качестве удалившего пользователя написано `Anonymous`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это может быть связано с удалением пользователя

Comment: @Grundy, но пользователь не может удалять комментарии под удалёнными сообщениями.